# How do I load data into the Data Portal of DIAdem with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I want to load a ".tdm" file into DIAdem (National Instruments) with a VBScript but can't find how to do this. I have Dialog which opens a browse-window, which returns the path as a string. So I was hoping to have a function which would work something like this:

```
Call Data.Root.ChannelGroups.Load(myStringWithThePath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed I got a tumbleweed-badge on this question. Here is the solution I found last week, so if anybody cares:

```
Set objDialog = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")

objDialog.Filter = "TDM-Datei(*.tdm)|*.tdm|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
objDialog.FilterIndex = 1

boolResult = objDialog.ShowOpen

If boolResult <> 0 Then
    Call Data.Root.ChannelGroups.RemoveAll()
    Call DataDelAll
    Call DataFileLoad(objDialog.FileName)
End If
```